# Set body of a span equal to a variable

Tags: css, vbscript, hta

I'm doing some testing with HTA's and I've come across a problem.
Here is the code I am using:

```
<script language="VBScript">
Public Game

Sub window_onload()
    Game="Help"
    sGame.body.InnerHTML=Game
    sName.body.InnerHTML=Game
End Sub

Sub strTest
    Game="Test"
End Sub
</script>

<body bgcolor="#42732D">

<div style="position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    top:45px;">

<span id = "sName" style="text-align:center;
    font-family:Small Fonts;
    font size:65px;
    z-index:1;
    color:#1C2433"
>

Yes

</span>

<span id = "sGame"
style="text-align:center;
position:absolute;
left:-4px;
font-family:Small Fonts;
font size:65px;
z-index:15;
color:#1094AF"
>
</span>
</div>

<input type="button" style="font-family:Small Fonts; font size:30px; color: white; background-color:grey" value="Testing" name="bTest" onclick="strTest">
</body>
```

What I'm trying to do is set two spans equal to the same variable (a hack to give the text a 3D look with separate colors) However, when I run `strTest`, which should change the spans from `"Yes"` to what the variable `Game` is equal to, nothing happens. How can I dynamically change the text of a span using a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<span>`s don't have a `body` property. Just use `innerHTML`.

Change:

```
Sub window_onload()
    Game="Help"
    sGame.body.InnerHTML=Game
    sName.body.InnerHTML=Game
End Sub
```

To:

```
Sub window_onload()
    Game="Help"
    sGame.innerHTML = Game
    sName.innerHTML = Game
End Sub
```

Here's the documentation for the [`HTMLSpanElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSpanElement) on Mozilla's site. As you can see, it doesn't define any properties. If you work your way up the hierarchy to [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), you'll see the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property.